# Dividing data from a large dataframe by data in a smaller dataframe based on indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two data frames. I want to create a new column in the first data frame by dividing by specific data in the second data frame, dependent on a date.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Count':  {('2020-02-01','Cat', '0'): 10,
                    ('2020-02-01','Dog', '1'): 7,
                    ('2020-02-01','Cat', '2'): 5,

                    ('2020-02-03','Cat', '0'): 3,
                    ('2020-02-03','Cat', '1'): 4,
                    ('2020-02-03','Dog', '2'): 10,

                    ('2020-02-05','Cat', '0'): 1,
                    ('2020-02-05','Dog', '1'): 20,
                    ('2020-02-05','Cat', '2'): 17,

                    ('2020-02-08','Dog', '0'): 13,
                    ('2020-02-08','Dog', '1'): 13,

                    ('2020-02-09','Dog', '2'): 14,
                    ('2020-02-09','Cat', '0'): 30,
                    ('2020-02-09','Dog', '1'): 12,
                    ('2020-02-09','Cat', '2'): 1}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1.index.names = ['Date', 'Animal', 'Dose'] 

data2 = {'Average':  {('2020-02-01','0'): 1,
                      ('2020-02-03','0'): 5,
                      ('2020-02-05','0'): 3,
                      ('2020-02-08','0'): 31,
                      ('2020-02-09','0'): 14}}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2.index.names = ['Date', 'Dose']
```

All Dates exist in both data frames.
How do I divide the values in the `'Count'` column of `df1` by the `'Average'` values in `df2` based on `'Date'`?

Obviously `df1['Divided'] = df1['Date','Count'].div[df2['Date','Average']` won't work, but that's kind of the idea.

I've tried all sorts of things up to and including converting to a dictionary and trying to map values, but I couldn't figure it out.

My expected results would look like this:

```
data3 = [10/1, 7/1, 5/1, 3/5, 4/5, 10/5, 1/3, 20/3, 17/3, 13/31, 13/31, 14/14, 30/14, 12/14, 1/14]

df1['Divided'] = data3

df1
```

Comment: kindly add ur expected output

Comment: thanks.  I just added the expected results to the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=['Animal', 'Dose'])
df2 = df2.reset_index(level=['Dose'])
df1["New_Value"] = df1['Count'].div(df2['Average'])
df1 = df1.reset_index().set_index(['Date', 'Animal', 'Dose'])
```

Output:

```
                      Count  New_Value
Date       Animal Dose                  
2020-02-01 Cat    0        10  10.000000
                  2         5   5.000000
           Dog    1         7   7.000000
2020-02-03 Cat    0         3   0.600000
                  1         4   0.800000
           Dog    2        10   2.000000
2020-02-05 Cat    0         1   0.333333
                  2        17   5.666667
           Dog    1        20   6.666667
2020-02-08 Dog    0        13   0.419355
                  1        13   0.419355
2020-02-09 Cat    0        30   2.142857
                  2         1   0.071429
           Dog    1        12   0.857143
                  2        14   1.000000
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Join 'df2' to the date of 'df1' to make the same number of lines and divide. Does it meet the intent of the question?

```
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

df3 = pd.merge(df1['Date'], df2, on='Date', how='inner')
df1['Divided'] = df1['Count'] / df3['Average']

df1
    Date    Animal  Dose    Count   Divided
0   2020-02-01  Cat 0   10  10.000000
1   2020-02-01  Cat 2   5   5.000000
2   2020-02-01  Dog 1   7   7.000000
3   2020-02-03  Cat 0   3   0.600000
4   2020-02-03  Cat 1   4   0.800000
5   2020-02-03  Dog 2   10  2.000000
6   2020-02-05  Cat 0   1   0.333333
7   2020-02-05  Cat 2   17  5.666667
8   2020-02-05  Dog 1   20  6.666667
9   2020-02-08  Dog 0   13  0.419355
10  2020-02-08  Dog 1   13  0.419355
11  2020-02-09  Cat 0   30  2.142857
12  2020-02-09  Cat 2   1   0.071429
13  2020-02-09  Dog 1   12  0.857143
14  2020-02-09  Dog 2   14  1.000000
```

Comment: I like this answer, too.  It was one of the things I was trying and couldn't figure out.  thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Get the dates for df1 into column position, and divide by an array of df2:

```
result = (df1
           #get dates into column position
          .unstack(0)
           #get your average values as a 1d array
          .div(df2.loc(axis=1)['Average'].array)
           #get dates back into index position
          .stack()
          .reorder_levels(['Date','Animal','Dose'])
          .sort_index()
         )

result


                          Count
Date    Animal  Dose    
2020-02-01  Cat 0   10.000000
                2   5.000000
            Dog 1   7.000000
2020-02-03  Cat 0   0.600000
                1   0.800000
            Dog 2   2.000000
2020-02-05  Cat 0   0.333333
                2   5.666667
            Dog 1   6.666667
2020-02-08  Dog 0   0.419355
                1   0.419355
2020-02-09  Cat 0   2.142857
                2   0.071429
            Dog 1   0.857143
                2   1.000000
```